# Cypress not working, Error 500 at Client Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress

im trying to use cypress for the first time and the default example project does not seem to work. On any browser, the browser loads, i get the 'controlled by automated software' message but it just keeps loading.

Running on Windows 10.

Im getting the following error:

An unexpected error occurred

There was an error reconnecting to the Chrome DevTools protocol. Please restart the browser.

Error: Unexpected server response: 500 at ClientRequest. (C:\Users\uktpmadegio\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.1.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:604:7) at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20) at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (_http_client.js:641:27) at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:126:17) at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:509:22) at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20) at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12) at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9) at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10) at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)

Error: There was an error reconnecting to the Chrome DevTools protocol. Please restart the browser.

Error: Unexpected server response: 500
at ClientRequest. (C:\Users\uktpmadegio\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.1.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:604:7)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (_http_client.js:641:27)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:126:17)
at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:509:22)
at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10)
at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)

```
at Object.get (C:\Users\uktpmadegio\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.1.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\lib\errors.js:988:15)
at C:\Users\uktpmadegio\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.1.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\lib\browsers\cri-client.js:85:40
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

Comment: Can you share test file? it seems you installed cypress globally, i suggest you to install locally in the repository you want to test

Comment: thanks for your reply. I was trying to follow the tutorial as described here: [link](https://docs.cypress.io/examples/examples/tutorials#1-Project-setup).  The application runs and loads up normally but I get the error when I try to run a test